# Stratonovich equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am having the following problem:

Consider the following stratonovich equation:

$dY_t=-\sin(Y_t)\cdot dt+s\cos(Y_t)\circ dB_t$

where $B_t$ is a regular brownian motion.

Then define the process $Z_t=\sin(Y_t)$.

I would now like to find the Ito-equation and the Stratonovich equation, that $Z_t$ satisfies.

My approach has been straighforward:

first setting $dZ_t=\sin'(Y_t)\cdot dY_t=\cos(Y_t)\cdot dY_t$.

Then, I use various rules from analysis to get

$dZ_t=\cos(Y_t)\cdot dY_t$

$dZ_t=\cos(\arcsin(Z_t))\cdot (-\sin(Y_t)\cdot dt+s\cos(Y_t)\circ dB_t)$

which after calculations give:

$dZ_t=-Z_t\cdot \sqrt{(1-Z_t^2)}\cdot dt+s(1-Z_t^2)\circ dB_t$.

Is that then the stratonovich equation that satisfies $Z_t$, or should I do something else?

Also, how can I from this find the Ito equation, which satisfies $Z_t$?

Thanks in advance.